# Is there a reasonable scenario for a stateful IComparer<T>?

Tags: .net, generics, icomparer

I have never written a stateful `IComparer<T>` with a default constructor. All standard library implementations which I've checked in Reflector are stateless as well. Therefore, I'd like to assume that I can freely cache `IComparer<T>` like this:

```
PriorityQueue<TPriority, TComparer> where TComparer : IComparer<TPriority>, new()
{
    private static TComparer _comparer = new TComparer();

    public PriorityQueue() {...}
    ...
}
```

instead of

```
PriorityQueue<TPriority>
{
    private IComparer<TPriority> _comparer;

    public PriorityQueue(IComparer<TPriority> comparer) { 
        _comparer = comparer;
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

So here is the question: have you ever written/seen an `IComparer<T>` for which this would break down? If yes, how common is it?

EDIT: The reason I really don't want the overhead of the second version in this case is that the data structure is persistent. It is implemented as a tree where nodes have no parent/root reference. So it wouldn't be one reference to comparer per queue, but one reference to comparer per node! My original design was just to use `IComparable<T>` and recommend writing a wrapper struct for custom comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, having a **static** comparer means you can't have different comparisons on different queues; this can be a problem... occasionally people *do* need a custom comparison; for example, if they don't control the type. My default approach would be:

```
PriorityQueue<TPriority>
{
    private IComparer<TPriority> _comparer;

    public PriorityQueue(IComparer<TPriority> comparer) { 
        _comparer = comparer;
        ...
    }

    public PriorityQueue() : this(Comparer<T>.Default) {}
}
```

Re stateful comparers; yes, I've written several - particularly for writing LINQ-style projection comparers... for example, something like:

```
public static class ProjectionComparer<TSource>
{
    public static IComparer<TSource> CompareBy<TValue>(
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
    {
        return CompareBy<TValue>(selector, Comparer<TValue>.Default);
    }
    public static IComparer<TSource> CompareBy<TValue>(
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector,
        IComparer<TValue> comparer)
    {
        return new ProjectionComparerItem<TValue>(
            selector, Comparer<TValue>.Default);
    }
    class ProjectionComparerItem<TValue> : IComparer<TSource>
    {
        private readonly IComparer<TValue> comparer;
        private readonly Func<TSource, TValue> selector;
        public ProjectionComparerItem(
            Func<TSource, TValue> selector,
            IComparer<TValue> comparer)
        {
            this.selector = selector;
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }
        public int Compare(TSource x, TSource y)
        {
            // TODO: some null stuff...
            return comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y));
        }
    }
}
```

which allows:

```
IComparer<Customer> comparer = ProjectionComparer<Customer>
          .CompareBy(cust => cust.Name);
```

instance "sort by name" comparison.

Comment: This is a good example, but it doesn't have a default constructor, so it couldn't get used accidentally in static case.

Comment: The point of parametrizing by `TComparer` is precisely to allow different comparisons. The queues with different comparisons will have different types, but I don't think merging (for example) queues with different comparisons makes much sense.

Comment: And my point is that you don't always want a type per comparison; the class(es) above allows lots of different comparisons with the same types; why force people to write a class?

Comment: I agree that it is useful. I was commenting specifically on the claim that different queues *can't* have different comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have, but I think it's fairly uncommon.

There are rare instances where you want to implement a comparison that's dependent on other data.  For example, we've got some spatial routines where we feed an axis that's used for comparison as part of the IComparer.

That being said, it's pretty easy to work around this by just using a separate comparer class, and that's probably a better design in many ways.  You are putting a limitation on the `IComparer<T>` implementation that does need to exist, though, so I would document your rationale.

My personal preference would be to make the `IComparer<T>` non-static, and provide two constructors - one that takes an external instance and one that creates a default comparer.  You have the extra overhead of a comparer per queue, but that's pretty minimal (nearly 0 if you have no state, since it's only a single object reference to an "empty" object).

Comment: I'd agree, but the overhead is greater than it seems; see the edit.

Comment: If the comparer is a struct with no elements, there's very little overhead... I would still probably do the one-per-queue approach, given the flexibility of it.

Comment: If the comparer is a struct, you really should be generic in it; if you just use it as `IComparer<T>`, you'll get the boxing overhead on each use!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach:

```
private class PriorityQueueImpl<TPriority, TComparer> where TComparer : IComparer<TPriority> {
    // all methods accept a TComparer
    // generic in TComparer to avoid boxing for struct TComparers and permit inlining for sealed TComparers
}

public struct PriorityQueue<TPriority, TComparer> where TComparer : IComparer<TPriority> {
    private readonly PriorityQueueImpl<TPriority, TComparer> _impl;
    private readonly TComparer _comparer;

    // methods delegate to _impl
}
```

I may go with it at least for some cases.